# SQLite database is locked

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

How do I sort this one out?

code:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO INPUT33 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name3,))      
c.execute("select MAX(rowid) from [input33];")
conn.commit()      
for rowid in cursor:break         
for elem in rowid:
    m = elem    
    print(m)
    c.execute("select MAX(rowid) from [input];")                    
    for rowid in c:break
    for elem in rowid:                            
    m = elem   
    c.execute("DELETE FROM input WHERE rowid = ?", (m,))
    conn.commit()
```

After running this, i get this:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: Why two separate cursors, `cursor` and `c`?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

When a database is accessed by multiple connections, and one of the processes modifies the database, the `SQLite` database is locked until that transaction is committed. The timeout parameter specifies how long the connection should wait for the lock to go away until raising an exception. *The default for the timeout parameter is 5.0 (five seconds)*.

Comment: is there a way to reduce the 5sec or a better solution?